# HTML form "required" attribute on Mobile Safari doesn't work

Tags: html, forms, mobile-safari, required

Mobile Safari on iPad is supposed to be HTML5-compliant, but it seems that the required attribute doesn't work. Anyone know why, or have a decent workaround that doesn't require a ton of JavaScript?

My code

```
<input type=email class=input placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
```

Comment: Can you try `<input type=email class=input placeholder="Email" name="email" required />` or `<input type=email class=input placeholder="Email" name="email" required="" />`.

Comment: Did you try with `required />` instead of `required>` ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's not supported in iOS yet: [when can I use: required](http://caniuse.com/#search=required).

Comment: As the link shows, Safari 10.1 and iOS 10.3 (both relesed on 27.03.2017) support the required attribute.

Comment: I can confirm that as May 2017, I am working on a project with the required tag and we tested it on iPhone and it ignored it and the form posted empty data.

Answer (score 16):

This is a jQuery solution to the issue, it highlights the input fields that have failed in a pinky colour too.

```js
$('form').submit(function(){
    var required = $('[required="true"]'); // change to [required] if not using true option as part of the attribute as it is not really needed.
    var error = false;

    for(var i = 0; i <= (required.length - 1);i++)
    {
        if(required[i].value == '') // tests that each required value does not equal blank, you could put in more stringent checks here if you wish.
        {
            required[i].style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255,155,155)';
            error = true; // if any inputs fail validation then the error variable will be set to true;     
        }
    }
                            
    if(error) // if error is true;
    {
        return false; // stop the form from being submitted.
    }
});
```

Comment: your solution is great.
I customized it to validate current form only, if you have more than one form on the page, by modifying second line as follow:

`code`var required = $('[required="true"]', this);`code`

Answer (score 3):

Since iOS 10.3, this attribute is supported.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something before the submit action like this:

```html
<form name="myForm" action="valid.html" onsubmit="checkValid()" method="post">
  ... ...
</form>
```

After pressing `submit` button, `checkValid()` is evoked before it actually submits. a return value of `true` will continue the submit action.

Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262797/html-form-action-and-onsubmit-issues) for further explanation.

Answer (score -1):

If you use PHP, you can add a validation like this

```
function validation(){

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $email = $_POST['email'];

     if(empty($email)){
        echo $error = "Your email cannot be empty";

      } else {
        return true; //or do something next here
     }
   }
```

You then add this function in php before your form.

Comment: This will be done on the server side. The `required` attribute is built into the browser and prevent your browser from sending incomplete content. In other words, the idea is to prevent PHP (in your case) from ever needing to validate that (even though you actually should do it anyway).